# Какая интенсивность изучения программирования?

Tags: java, c++, веб-программирование

Хочу увидеть ответы старичков.

Вот я изучил html, css, js, php, laravel на среднем уровне. 
Но пока я это изучал, появились новые разные штуки, всякие пакеты, сборщики и т.п.
И опять приходится очень много доучивать и потом опять доучивать.

При просмотре вакансий, никогда не попадал в свой стек. 
Кому то нужен программист на yii, кому то на lravel, битрикс, симфони, что бы знал кучу всяких пакетов, типа эластика, кому то нужен фулстекер и из-за этого работу найти очень сложно, даже если выполняешь тестовое задание, про тебя забывают.

Так вот, неужели такое происходит во всех направлениях программирования или только в веб разработке?

Если я её брошу и допустим, захочу изучать робототехнику, меня точно такое же ждёт?

Comment: Доучивать вам придется до конца вашей карьеры - это специфика профессии программиста. Если вы ничего не учите, значит вы стоите на месте и все, кто учит, вас обходит на рынке. Если вы ничего не изучаете долгое время, считайте, что вы уже на обочине карьеры.

Comment: чтобы обучение давалось быстро и легко, надо знать основы CS. Бекенд сейчас, как и 15 лет назад, генерирует ответы на запросы. Фротенд все также отвечает за взаимодействие с пользоватиелем. Всякие MVC / MVVM были придуманы много лет назад, паттерны/практики/алгоритмы были и 20 лет назад. Потому если будете знать основы, вам не придется учить, например, Angular с нуля, вам придется только понять, как тот или иной паттерн работает во том или ином фреймворке.

Comment: Ищите вакансии по знаниям, а не в вакансиях то, что нужно дальше изучать. Если не брать какие-то уж совсем специфичные вещи, то не важно какой язык программирования или технологию изучаете — работу специалист найдёт всегда, главное не бросаться во все стороны сразу. И ещё, многие напишут, что программисты учатся всю жизнь и прочее и прочее. Но это совершенно не обязательно, есть куча народа, которая получает свою зарплату и ничему новому не учится. Каждому своё.

Comment: Посто в вебе такое наиболее выраженно, на мой взгляд. Людям лень разбираться в существующих фремворках, и они пишут каждый день [новый](https://habr.com/ru/post/312022/):)

Answer (score 4):

Нормальные программисты всегда учатся. Даже старички. Перестал учится - все...

> Так вот, неужели такое происходит во всех направлениях программирования или только в веб разработке?

просто в веб разработке, если не написал свой фреймворк/пакет, то как то не то. (если что, то это полушутка).

> Если я её брошу и допустим, захочу изучать робототехнику, меня точно такое же ждёт?

а тут придется возможно изучать схемотехнику, программирование контроллеров и так далее. И язык поменять (хотя есть и чипы, которые поддерживают js)

Comment: > "Нормальные программисты всегда учатся. Даже старички"...

 Не только программисты, все нормальные специалисты учатся всегда

Answer (score 0):

Главное приобрести базовые знания. Владеть своим языком программирования на достаточно хорошем уровне и знать хотя бы небольшую часть технологий, которые применяются с ним. Что касается всяких новых фичей и постоянных обновлений, то я считаю, что они все же не революционны, и программист среднего уровня, или даже новичок при желании смогут их освоить в достаточно короткое время.